# Trying to Pivot_long a dataframe in R

Tags: r, pivot

I would like to pivot the following df so that the three date columns are replaced by a Value and Date column.  So, Jan_2023, Feb_2023 and Mar_2023 columns replaced by Date and Value columns.

```
Short_Name <- c("BE", "BE", "DE", "DE", "BE", "BE", "DE", "DE")
Long_Name <- c("BELGIUM", "BELGIUM", "GERMANY", "GERMANY", "BELGIUM", "BELGIUM", "GERMANY", "GERMANY")

Category <- c("Original", "Discount", "Original", "Discount","Original", "Discount", "Original", "Discount")

Jan_2023 <- c(100, 20, 90, 10, 120,40, 80, 25)
Feb_2023 <- c(110, 30, 90, 15, 150,40, 80, 15)
Mar_2023 <- c(120, 40, 90, 10, 130,40, 90, 10)

df_original <- data.frame(Short_Name, Long_Name, Category, Jan_2023, Feb_2023, Mar_2023)
```

Been trying with  pivot_long but not working?

Comment: It can be frustrating to help with questions when the code in the question clearly does not parse much less execute. Please try the code that you're asking us to try, see where it fails, and fix it. (Hint: `Jan 2023` is not a valid column name, either replace/remove the space or wrap it in backticks everywhere, i.e., `\`Jan 2023\``.)

Comment: Don't worry about the apology, just please fix your data (or just accept akrun's answer if it is sufficient).

Comment: I could no longer edit it?

Comment: you can _always_ [edit] your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df_original, cols = matches("\\d{4}$"), names_to = 'Date')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 24 × 5
   Short_Name Long_Name Category Date     value
   <chr>      <chr>     <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>
 1 BE         BELGIUM   Original Jan 2023   100
 2 BE         BELGIUM   Original Feb 2023   110
 3 BE         BELGIUM   Original Mar 2023   120
 4 BE         BELGIUM   Discount Jan 2023    20
 5 BE         BELGIUM   Discount Feb 2023    30
 6 BE         BELGIUM   Discount Mar 2023    40
 7 DE         GERMANY   Original Jan 2023    90
 8 DE         GERMANY   Original Feb 2023    90
 9 DE         GERMANY   Original Mar 2023    90
10 DE         GERMANY   Discount Jan 2023    10
# … with 14 more rows
```